# Replace the day in a date in to fit the pd.to_datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have a data frame with multiple columns and multiple rows. In one of these columns there are dates that take the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I am trying to convert this using `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])` but am getting the following error because there are multiple records that have `00` in the place of a missing month or day:

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

I don't want to do `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors = 'coerce')` because I want to keep whatever data is there.

I would like all the dates that are missing days or months or both (e.g `11/00/2018, 00/13/2018, or 00/00/2018)` to have the value `01` where the value is missing (e.g `11/01/2018, 01/13/2018, 01/01/2018`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex to replace `00`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['11/00/2018', '00/13/2018', '00/00/2018']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col'])
replace = df['col'].replace('00/', '01/', regex=True)
result = pd.to_datetime(replace)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0   2018-11-01
1   2018-01-13
2   2018-01-01
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Less susceptible to the issues of the previous answer, but I'm not a fan at all of replacing _unknown_ values with a default value here if this ever has to go forwards for analysis. Not the downvoter, but I really think some consideration needs to be made about how this could skew analysis

Comment: Well I believe this does answer what the OP asked or I am mistaken?

Comment: Hence why I'm not the downvoter :) But this result is likely more harmful than just dropping the data in this case if they actually want to analyse things by date